# Notepad++: How to remove text in between two specified strings using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have following lines of data:

> X1+0X2+0X3+0X4+0X5+0X6+0X7-0.25X8-0.25X9-0.25X10-0.25X11+0X12+0X13+0X14+0.8X15+0X16+0X17+0X18
>
> X1+0X2+0X3+0X4+0X5+0X6+0X7-0.25X8-0.25X9-0.25X10-0.25X11+0X12+0X13+0X14+0.89404X15+0X16+0X17+0X18
>
> X1+0X2+0X3+0X4+0X5+0X6+0X7-0.25X8-0.25X9-0.25X10-0.25X11+0X12+0X13+0X14+0.93532X15+0X16+0X17+0X18

I wish to delete the string `X15`, the preceding `+`, and any characters in between using regex.

For example, the regex replace should return the following from my sample lines:

> X1+0X2+0X3+0X4+0X5+0X6+0X7-0.25X8-0.25X9-0.25X10-0.25X11+0X12+0X13+0X14+0X16+0X17+0X18
>
> X1+0X2+0X3+0X4+0X5+0X6+0X7-0.25X8-0.25X9-0.25X10-0.25X11+0X12+0X13+0X14+0X16+0X17+0X18
>
> X1+0X2+0X3+0X4+0X5+0X6+0X7-0.25X8-0.25X9-0.25X10-0.25X11+0X12+0X13+0X14+0X16+0X17+0X18

Can someone please provide some suggestions and thoughts on this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Notepad++ but the way I would do that is:

Replace:

```
\+[^+]*X15
```

With nothing

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to use it, but it displays an error as "Invalid regular expression". I am quite new to regular expression.

Comment: I think I figured that out. Since + is a regular expression keyword, I would have to give the search string as \+[^\+]*X15   Thank you very much for help. I appreciate it

Comment: There are different ways that programs handle regular expressions. I didn't know if Notepad++ used + or not. Now I know. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Naren You don't need to put the backslash within the negated class, that is, it's perfectly fine with `\+[^+]*X15`.

Comment: @Naren If this answer solved your question, please select it as accepted.